Comparator output stays low
I am doing a DC sweep across V1 on the schematic below to find out when the MCP6566 comparators will output a high. My circuit is from the design below.

My ORCad capture schematic is below

As there is no spice model for the MCP6567 comparator, I have used two MCP6566 comparators.
For some reason, no matter what the voltage across V1 is, the comparators do not output a high which is shown below.

For a test, separate the outputs of the two comparators (give each one its own 10K pull-up).  You may find that there is never a state where the outputs of both comparators will be High at the same time, which would allow the combined output to be High.

The comparators are working perfectly.

In your second schematic, I don't see the common input of the comparators connected anywhere except to the two capacitors. This obviously won't work in the simulation. Also in this schematic I see further problems with the amplifier. I can't see the common mode input voltage value and the 3 V differential input voltage seems too high. These are not visible in the first schematic because it is not known where the two inputs will be connected. So, for the test, there should be a common mode voltage on both inputs and a differential input voltage relative to them. Since the reference voltage is 1.8 V, the differential input voltage must vary in the + - range in order to test the full range of the comparators (e.g. sine wave input voltage).
